# How can I indicate/print the distinct combinations to this Fibonacci number-based program?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I am constructing a function to determine how many distinct ways one can climb to the top of a staircase (can either climb 1 or 2 steps). Although I have gotten the main function to print out how many ways, I am confused on how to print the specific combinations i.e. There are three ways to climb to the top: (1, 1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int climbStairs(int n);

int main()
{
  int s = 4;
  cout << "There are " << climbStairs(s) << " ways to climb to the top: ";           
  return 0;
}

int climbStairs(int n)    
{    
  if(n == 0) return 0;
  if(n == 1) return 1;
    int one = 1;
    int two = 0;
    int result = 0;   
    for(int i = 1;i <= n;i++)
    {
       result = one + two;
       two = one;
       one = result;
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Any explanation on how to go about printing the combinations will help, thank you so much!

Comment: In your for loop, collect the steps taken.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the variables `one` and `two` being integers, define them as sets of "paths". Then, do the same thing, except `result` is `one` with a 1 appended to all the "paths" in it plus `two` with a 2 appended to all the "paths" in it.

The algorithm looks something like this (I would recommend trying to do this yourself before looking at my code):

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
std::set<std::string> climbStairs(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return {""};
    if(n == 1)
        return {"1"};
    std::set<std::string> one({"1"}), two({""}), result;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        result.clear();
        for(const std::string &path : one)
        {
            result.insert(path + '1');
        }
        for(const std::string &path : two)
        {
            result.insert(path + '2');
        }
        two = move(one);
        one = move(result);
    }
    return one;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> s = climbStairs(5);
    for(const std::string &path : s)
    {
        std::cout << path << '\n';
    }
}
```

This is the best way that I know of.